# How to attach cloth to line?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, physics

So I'm trying to make a string of bunt flags (triangle flags lined in a row).

I can't get the flag to stay attached to the line. I've already tried Hook modifier with Data Transfer modifier, Parenting the flag to line, and even hooking vertex group to an empty obj and parenting the flag to that...It just keeps falling away.

HELP!

Comment: have you determined a Pin group?

Comment: Are you trying to have simulated flags or just flags on the line?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make something like this:

[image]

you need a mesh line (subdivided). Give it a cloth modifier.

The mesh line should have a pin/vertex group like this:

[image]

add two hook modifiers with a vertex group of one vertex each like this:

[image]

[image]

The hooks "move" the flag with the line, so add them these copy location constraint:

[image]

make sure that the hook modifiers of the flag are before the cloth modifier:

[image]